# What camera to use for classroom/lecture recording?

Tags: camera

We want to install HD IP cameras in our classrooms to record lectures and make them available online.

We are having a hard time finding the right one. Most are geared towards surveillance.

Any recommendations?

Room size: large classroom seating about 70 students

Camera specs required: Audio/in for wireless microphone, 1080p, data transfer over ethernet.

Comment: What solution did you use? How far does the camera need to be from the teacher? How wide of a scene do you need to record (e.g., width of chalkboard so about 30 feet?) We're building something that might meet your needs, would love to hear what solution you chose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at these (I don't know your price range so I leave options in the link):

http://www.logitech.com/en-us/webcam-communications/webcams

Update:

For more professional solutions:

http://www.crestron.com/resources/product_and_programming_resources/catalogs_and_brochures/online_catalog/default.asp?jump=1&model=CAPTURELIVEHD

combined with:

http://www.crestron.com/resources/product_and_programming_resources/catalogs_and_brochures/online_catalog/default.asp?cat=1058&subcat=1506&id=2220

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Not sure if a Webcam would be suitable... distance and data transfer come to mind. It will be installed on the ceiling/wall of a large classroom a bit away from the lecturer. Also need to have audio in for lecturers microphone.

Comment: @Tom I updated my answer with a link to a more professional oriented package.

Comment: That is a professional package... one of many that I have looked at and the price is accordingly high. I'd rather focus on just a camera at the moment.